# С#. Копирование файлов из под пользователя LocalSystem

Tags: c#, .net

Есть доменная сеть предприятия. Есть служба которая работает на серваке, служба крутится под пользователем *LocalSystem*. Эта служба должна скопировать файл из локальной папки, в папку на компьютер в сети, и там его запустить(это обычный *exe* файл, установочник).

Действия такие должны быть:

1. Проверить, есть ли необходимая папка на удаленном компьютере. Если её нету, то создать;
2. Скопировать файл в папку из пункта 1;
3. Запустить.

При создании папки и копировании файлов у меня всегда падает ошибка, что нет доступа. Подскажите как сделать или почему такая проблема возникает.

Было бы хорошо, если бы предоставили рабочий код для этой задачи.

Comment: `под пользователем LocalSystem`, `в папку на компьютер в сети`, `ошибка что нету доступа` - по моему все логично

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. Если честно, то я не понял вашего комментария.

Comment: @tym32167 ну логично может и да, но какое решение этой проблемы?

Comment: Решение очевидно же - лазать по сети от имени того юзера, у которого есть доступ это делать. Ну, или добавлять права доступа к удаленным компам LocalSystem, хотя это слегка нелогично будет выглядеть

Comment: @tym32167 дело в том что я не могу понять как скопировать файл используя "лазать по сети от имени того юзера, у которого есть доступ это делать". Так как служба у меня работает от имени LocalSystem. Поменять это можно, но это крайний случий

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. к счастью да, это не вредоностное ПО. Цель такого функционала, чтобы с сервера скинуть установочник клиенской части приложения и запустить его там.

Comment: @Kirill'luridSNK'F. я не хочу готовое решение, но я хочу чтобы мне посдказали куда копать. ruSO - для это место куда я обращаюсь когда уже сам перепробовал куча способов и ни один не подходит, чтобы более опытные коллеги мне подсказали в чем проблема и в принцапе да, тут подсказывают решение за "спасибо", а не за деньги.

Comment: Давайте определимся. Служба у вас работает от имени юзера, у которого нет прав на выполнение вашего действия. То есть продолжая работать так дальше, вы проблему не решите. Либо запускайте службу от другого юзера, либо давайте право доступа текущему юзеру - причем не важно, крайний это для вас вариант или нет, вы полюбому с текущим юзером без изменения его прав ничего не скопируете.

Comment: @tym32167 неужели нет способа, скопировать файл от имени другого пользователя?

Comment: Можно конечно, вам надо только запустить код копирования от имени другого юзера. Например https://platinumdogs.me/2008/10/30/net-c-impersonation-with-network-credentials/

Answer (score 0):

Для того чтобы вы могли что-то делать на сторонней машине вам нужна учетка с правами достаточными для управления требуемой машиной (в вашем случае предположу, что нужна учетка с правами доменного админа).
Все дальнейшее может решить данное ПО от [PSEXEC](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я использовал psexec(только конечно, версии 2.0,2) и проблема так и не рашилась. Запускал его я используя учетную запись доменного администратора.